# React/GraphQL: SyntaxError: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal?

Tags: reactjs, graphql, aws-amplify

I got a website based on React/GraphQL up running. The webpage works fine on Windows and Android Phones. However it comes blank when I try to open it in my iPhone X. Then, I connected it to MacBook with Web Inspector and see the error message:

`SyntaxError: No identifiers allowed directly after numeric literal`

pointing to the start of the script:

```
(this.webpackJsonpperfexam = this.webpackJsonpperfexam || []).push([[2], [function(e, t, r) {
    "use strict";
    e.exports = r(263)
}, function(e, t, r) {
```

I also got blank page when I try to open it on my iPhone X using Chrome. However, Chrome on my MacBook can open it without problem. I believe I was able to open it from Safari on my MacBook earlier, but today, I got the same error.

What could it be?

Comment: what's in the `r`, how param is processed?

Comment: I have no idea. This is code generated by build script.

Comment: try to explore how it's processed ... if it is not a simple value ...  maybe build/minimizing script produces only numerical named identifiers, not allowed in some [by apple] scenarios?

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be caused by a bug in the latest version (as of now) of

> graphql-hooks-memcache v1.3.2

and once I downgrade to v1.3.1, the problem went away. Please refer to this [github](https://github.com/nearform/graphql-hooks/issues/496) discussion.